# How to use COUNT + Select statements at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I count the number of products from an order using COUNT & Select?

```
SELECT OrderNo, ProdID, (COUNT(prodID)
FROM orders..allorders ao
JOIN orderProd..products pr
ON orderNo = OrderNum
WHERE OrderNo = '123456'
```

I just need to list the order number along with the number of products on it.

Cheers.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_Number with Partition by or you can also use group by clause. For Example

Using Partition by

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo, ProdID, COUNT(prodID) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo) [#OfProduct]
FROM orders..allorders ao
JOIN orderProd..products pr ON orderNo = OrderNum
```

Using Group by

```
SELECT OrderNo, ProdID, COUNT(prodID) [#OfProduct]
FROM orders..allorders ao
JOIN orderProd..products pr ON orderNo = OrderNum
GROUP BY OrderNo, ProdID
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should perhaps comment on the difference, as these two queries will return different results for the count